# How to show my "app action" in google assistant, after user requesting by voice like "Ok Google, make me online"?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-voice-actions

Am working on a android project, where user wants to change his status online/offline through voice command. Whenever user says "Ok Google, make me online"

1.My action should be routed to my application context from google assistant, there I can change user status online/offline, is it possible?.

If not possible, can I do like this.

2.Whenever user says "Ok Google, make me online" can google assistant show button with my application icon like this,(but that should be specific for my app)

[image]

If above is possible, from the google assistant, I can click on the button and route user to my app, there I can do my task.

can you tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would want to achieve the described usecase using [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) 
It not currently available for developer preview, but it will come soon.

You may also want to see this Google IO 2018 Talk [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0uYZ4rTOrk) describing the same flow you want to achieve.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I watched the above Google IO 2018 video you have given. Can I achieve the same this using DialogFlow.

Comment: DialogFlow is meant to create some actions within Google Assistante and will direct interact with backend apis you created. So, It would not work as per your thinking. It would be like you are creating some question answer module within google assistante. Android app would not be in picture in this case.